# issue with a xmlns

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml file and an xslt file.

The xml file has a xmlns="exa:com.test" attribute.

If i remove this attribute in the xml the xpath sentences in my xslt works. But if i leave it, doesnt work.

Im using the following code to mix xml and xslt:

```
XslCompiledTransform transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();

transformer.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("xslt\\searchresults.xslt"));  

transformer.Transform(xmlreader, null, utf8stringwriter);
```

What im doing wrong? How could i mix xml and xslt if the xml has the xmlns attribute on top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xmlns` attribute without prefix name replaces the default namespace, so that your query matches nodes with a different (empty) namespace. You need to use a prefixed namespace in the XSLT XPath queries (or a [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) for isolated XPath queries) and your queries will work again as expected.

In the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:exa="exa:com.test">
```

Then, assuming that you used to match for instance `xyz`, you now change your query like this:

```
<xsl:template match="exa:xyz"> ...
```

In general you might want to read some docs on XML namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted though, though the namespace string is to just be seen as an exact literal string that is used as an identifier with no other meaning. The string *must* conform to an IANA uri, this is to guarantee uniqueness of namespaces. Some parsers refuse to parse namespaces that do not conform.

Also note that because they are strings `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` and for instance `http://w3.org/1999/xhtml/` are for the purposes of namespaces completely different namespaces.

You might want to read up on how namespaces in XML work. `exa:com.test` is as far as I know not a valid namespace string.